# Sencha Touch 2: Background CSS changes by panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Maybe I am missing something but it seems like a bug in Sencha Touch that you can't target TitleBar with specific panels with CSS if you are using the Getting Started template as your base model.

The Main.js (which contains TitleBar) calls all the other panels since the other panels are children of the Main.js where the TitleBar is so the children are not able to set the background color of the parent. In which case if you want the navigation bar (TitleBar) on the bottom of the screen to change colors from the Home.js page to your child pages it is not possible. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

```
<div class="Sencha-App">
    <div class="Panel"></div>
    <div class="TitleBar"> </div>
</div>
```

The problem would be easily solved if if TitleBar was a child of Panel but since it is only a child of your Sencha-App there is no way to make the TitleBar dynamic with CSS. Does this mean that the only thing I can do is use JavaScript to find if there is a class equal to "myPanel" and if so set the background of TitleBar to some color? Or use some architecture other than what they use in the Getting Started tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you......
To change color/style of toolbar you can create your specific UI in .scss file
and compile it using compass which will reflect changes in your .css file
then just set this UI to your toolbar

$base-color: #279806;
$base-gradient: 'glossy';
$base-active:#279806;
@include sencha-tabbar-ui('TabUI', $base-color, $base-gradient,  $base-active);

var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        ui:'TabUI'
       });

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something here or I don't understand SASS well enough. This will allow you to change the color of your TabPanel but this still doesn't allow for the TabPanel to change colors as the panels change, does it? SASS can't reference parents either so I am not sure what this would accomplish, can you explain how it would change color as I change panels? Thanks for your response.